Is Spartan prover time shorter than Groth16?
I want to know whether in zkSNARK implementations, Spartan has a shorter prover time than Groth16. I know this must depend on a variety of factors like the underlying curve or the complexity of the circuit. Suppose I'm using BLS12-381 (or 377) and my circuits are not simple i.e. 3 seconds to prove using Groth16 on 4 CPU cores.
Is Spartan likely to have a faster or slower prover time than Groth16? I'm trying to optimize my zkSNARk for prover time and have already implemented it in Groth16. I want to  know if Spartan is worth implementing to see if it outperforms Groth16.
